# Is this a decent way to create an EntityManager?

Tags: c++, beginner

I'm pretty new to C++.  I'm trying to design a `EntityManager` system, and so far this is what I have:

```
#ifndef ENTITY_MANAGER
#define ENTITY_MANAGER

#include "Entity.h"
#include "Airplane.h"
#include "Runway.h"
#include "Customer.h"
#include <unordered_map>

class EntityManager
{
private:
    typedef std::unordered_map<int, Entity*> EntityMap;

    EntityMap entityMap;
public:
    /*
    Gets an instance of the EntityManager
    */
    static EntityManager* instance();

    /*
    Creation and Deletion
    */

    /*
    Registers an Entity
    */
    void registerEntity(Entity* entity)
    {
        entityMap.insert(std::pair<int, Entity*>(entity->getId(), entity));
    }

    /*
    Removes an Entity by its ID
    */
    void removeEntity(int id)
    {
        entityMap.erase(id);
    }

    /*
    Removes an Entity by its instance
    */
    void removeEntity(Entity* entity)
    {
        removeEntity(entity->getId());
    }

    /*
    Gets an Entity by its id
    */
    Entity* getById(int id)
    {
        return entityMap.at(id);
    }

    /*
    Gets all the Airplanes
    */
    std::set<Airplane*> getAirplanes()
    {
        std::set<Airplane*> result;
        for (std::unordered_map<int, Entity*>::iterator it = entityMap.begin(); it != entityMap.end(); it++)
        {
            Entity* e = it->second;
            Airplane* plane = dynamic_cast<Airplane*>(e);
            if (plane)
            {
                result.insert(plane);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /*
    Gets all the Runways
    */
    std::set<Runway*> getRunways()
    {
        std::set<Runway*> result;
        for (std::unordered_map<int, Entity*>::iterator it = entityMap.begin(); it != entityMap.end(); it++)
        {
            Entity* e = it->second;
            Runway* runway = dynamic_cast<Runway*>(e);
            if (runway)
            {
                result.insert(runway);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /*
    Gets all the Customers
    */
    std::set<Customer*> getCustomers()
    {
        std::set<Customer*> result;
        for (std::unordered_map<int, Entity*>::iterator it = entityMap.begin(); it != entityMap.end(); it++)
        {
            Entity* e = it->second;
            Customer* customer = dynamic_cast<Customer*>(e);
            if (customer)
            {
                result.insert(customer);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
};
#endif
```

A little background:

- `Entity` is my base class, which handles assigning itself an id, etc.
- `Airplane` is a subclass of Entity, which has methods that describe its size, fuel, etc
- `Runway` is a subclass of `Entity`, which also has methods to describe its size
- `Customer` is a subclass of `Entity`, which has methods describing its AI state, etc

I'm looking for any help I can get in things like code correction and design flaws.

Comment: There is no ownership associated with your code. Who owns a pointer? Is it the entity manager. PS. Stop using pointers. In modern C++ you should practically never see a pointer unless you are building a container and then it should all be internal. Pass things around with ownership symantics defined this means references or smart pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Ahhhhhhhhh

```
static EntityManager* instance();
```

No ownership associated with even the manager.
If I get a manager. Who is responsible for destroying it?

```
// Do this.
// Use the classic singleton pattern.
static EntityManager& instance()
{
     static EntityManager   managerInstance;
     return managerInstance;
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern/1008289#1008289

Who owns the entity?

```
void registerEntity(Entity* entity)
```

Is the manager supposed to take ownership. Which means it will take responsibility for destroying the entity? Or are you giving the manager a reference it can use but does not own (thus it will not destroy).

As it stands. This is completely the wrong way of doing it. Once you tell me how you want to define the semantics of the interface I can tell you how to proceed.

---

### Update The manager is supposed to take ownership.

So lets continue:

```
void registerEntity(Entity* entity)
{
    entityMap.insert(std::pair<int, Entity*>(entity->getId(), entity));
}
```

From the interface you can tell that the manager takes ownership. As a result it can easily be called like this:

```
Airplane    airplane;
EntityManager::instance()->registerEntity(&airplane);
```

Now what will happen in your code. I suspect it will blow up at some point in the distant future. Try tracking that bug down.

The way to do this is to tell the manager he is supposed to take ownership. To do this your interface is supposed to take a `std::unique_ptr`. Also a couple of potential bugs to watch out for. Somebody may pass you a NULL in which case calling `getId()` is going to generate undefined behavior (by that I mean crash).

```
int registerEntity(std::unique_ptr<Entity>&& entity)
{
    if (!entity.get())
    {    return -1;
    }

    entityMap.insert(std::pair<int, Entity*>(entity->getId(), std::move(entity)));
    return entity->getId();
}
```

Notice I am moving the smart pointer into the `entityMap`. This shows that you are moving ownership into the map. It must also be smart enough to hold the smart pointers. So you have two options:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<Entity>> EntityMap;
```

Alternatively boost has a pointer container library, where the container takes ownership. Unfortunately they don't have unordered_map but they do have map.

```
boost::ptr_map<int, Entity> EntityMap;
```

Using the boost pointer containers has the advantage as access to the elements in the container make them look like objects (not pointers) thus using with any of the standard algorithms is trivial (Note: using algorithms on normal containers that hold pointers is a pain because of the extra de-reference involved).

Anyway either technique will remove the problem of memory leaks.

No check for NULL. Also I see no advantage of having this interface when the previous one `void removeEntity(int)` does exactly the same thing and does not have the disadvantage of ownership semantics.

```
void removeEntity(Entity* entity)
{
    removeEntity(entity->getId());
}
```

Returning a pointer here:

```
Entity* getById(int id)
{
    return entityMap.at(id);
}
```

Does this give you ownership of the object back?
I would think not. If you return a pointer you open yourself up to the user being confused and deleting the pointer.

```
Entity* plane = EntityManager::instance()->getById(12);
// WORK on place
delete plane;     // BANG
```

So return a reference to indicate the caller is not getting ownership back. This does open the question of how do do you handle values that would have returned NULL previously. I would handle this by having an existence test. So for ID that you are not sure about you can validate before a retrieval.

```
Entity& getById(int id) const
{
    return *entityMap[id];   // de-reference the smart pointer.
}
bool checkById(int id)
{
    return entityMap.find(id) != entityMap.end();
}
```

Comment: I keep hearing that singleton shouldn't be used freely.  Is this one situation where it could be used?  I just want to make sure since I have very little understanding of it.

Comment: Singeltons are bad if you do not disassociate creation from retrieval. Unfortunately most examples (including the one above) don't. This is ually because we try and trach one pattern at a time. But Singeltons are one of those patterns were you really need to disassociate creation from retrival from the start. So really you should use Singelton in association with a builder pattern so that you can introduce an alternative technique for creating the object (thus allowing you to use other objects for testing and validation).

Comment: Okay.  I should start reading your articles as well.  I'm slowly trying to work up to more advanced C++.

Comment: @Jamal: Hope the answer below helps.

Comment: I'm taking a look at it now. :-)

Comment: The manager is supposed to take ownership.

Comment: I've changed my code so that the entity gets deleted when it is removed from the map, hence stopping that memory leak

Answer (score 1):

Since it has been said already, I will leave the issue at "figure out what's responsible for memory management" without further explanation.

I have a few things to add: DRY, DRY, DRY!  (ha.. ha... tumbleweed)

It is possible that some day, you will want to change your container type.  Maybe you import a library, maybe you need different performance or thread safety, maybe you write something entirely new that better serves your purposes.  You did half the work of protecting yourself from this change by making a `typedef` for `EntityMap`, but you also have `std::unordered_map` throughout your code, as well as its corresponding iterator.  You can DRY that up by using the `EntityMap` instead of `std::unordered_map` in *all* cases.

Possibly add another `typedef` for the iterator type.  That's just to save some keystrokes, though, rather than typing out `EntityMap::iterator` every time.  You probably won't ever change the fact that you need an iterator specific to your container, so `EntityMap::iterator` is also fine if you don't care for brevity.

The other thing I see repeated over and over is the code to select a subset of your `Entity`s based on their subclass.  I doubt that your `EntityManager`'s role includes enforcing the class hierarchy, so you don't want the manager coupling to it.  That makes your manager brittle to any extensions of `Entity` you may make later - at best, every new type requires not only its own code and header, but also a change to the manager class, lest it remain un-queryable.

There are two ways to go about reducing that coupling.  Probably real OO gurus can think of more, but I'll stick with the simplest:

```
class EntityManager {
    /*...*/
public:
    /*...*/
    template<class EntitySubclass> std::set<EntitySubclass*> getAllSubclass() {
        std::set<EntitySubclass*> result;
        for (EntityMap::iterator it = entityMap.begin(); it != entityMap.end(); it++) {
            Entity* e = it->second;
            EntitySubclass* specificThing = dynamic_cast<EntitySubclass>(e);
            if (specificThing) {
                result.insert(specificThing);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

That way, all of your consumers' subclass queries become:

```
std::set<Airplane*> planes = myManager.getAllSubclass<Airplane>();
std::set<Customer*> customers = myManager.getAllSubclass<Customer>();
/* supposing tomorrow, your entities include coconuts and two */
/* varieties of swallows. */
std::set<Swallow*> swallows = myManager.getAllSubclass<Swallow>();
std::set<AfricanSwallow*> africanSwallows = myManager.getAllSubclass<AfricanSwallow>();
std::set<EuropeanSwallow*> europeanSwallows = myManager.getAllSubclass<EuropeanSwallow>();
std::set<Coconut*> coconuts = myManager.getAllSubclass<Coconut>();
```

Notice that in that example, I have expanded your set of `Entity` subclasses considerably and even added a level of hierarchy (the two types of `Swallow`), and the manager can handle them *without writing any additional code*.

Alternatively, if you want to keep your existing queries as shortcuts, you should still write the template method shown above, but you can make it private, then invoke it from the non-template query functions.  That would still require you to add a method every time you add a subclass, but it would be very easy to write and maintain those methods.

Comment: No problem!  We usually use a check mark and/or upvote to indicate "exactly what I needed" here =D.  Good luck with your airplanes, and try to keep the customers DRY =D.

Answer (score 0):

To answer @Jamal's comment:

> I keep hearing that singleton shouldn't be used freely. Is this one
> situation where it could be used? I just want to make sure since I
> have very little understanding of it.

**Please do not vote on this.**

#### Singleton done correctly using a factory

This is done using a factory. But you can use any other builder technique.
**Note**: This does not answer the question whether Singetons are a good idea or should be used or even when they should be used. Only that **if you use them** you should disassociate creation from retrieval.

```
class MyManager
{
   public:
        static void SetMyManagerFactory(MyManagerFactory& extraFact)
        {
            // If you are setting a manager then
            // your program is wrong if it is not going to be useful.
            if (alreadyBuilt(true))
            {    throw std::runtime_error("Factory already useless");
            }
            factory = &extraFact;
        }
        static MyManager& getInstance()
        {
            // disassociate building from retrieval.
            static std::unique_ptr<MyManager> managerInstance = buildInstance();
            return *managerInstance;
        }
    private:
        static std::unique_ptr<MyManager> buildInstance()
        {
            // Create an instance.
            // Note that the only instance has been created.
            // Thus if you try and set a factory after this you are out of look.
            alreadyBuilt();
            return factory
                     ? factory->buildMyManager();
                     : std::unique_ptr<MyManager>(new MyManager);
        }
        static bool alreadyBuilt(bool test = false)
        {
            static bool alreadyBuild = false;

            // If this is just a test return the state.
            if (test) {return alreadyBuild;}

            // If you are not testing. We must want to set the state.
            // Set the built to true. And return it for good measure.
            alreadyBuild = true;
            return alreadyBuild;
        }
        static MyManagerFactory*   factory;
};
```

Comment: You're also welcome to make this CW in case you do get votes.

Comment: I think I can understand this after some time.  I first need to understand the very basics of singleton.  Thanks. :-) To ensure this answer in some way addresses the *OP*'s question, you may mention how it can or cannot be used to improve the code.